# Jquery: change value of a dropdown... when triggered through a delegate event

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have two dropdowns, and I want it so that, when the user changes the first dropdown, the second gets updated automatically to the same value. Due to some complicated reasons, I have to trigger the change via an `on()` delegate event. My code is like this:

```
<form>

    <select id="destino_1">
    <option value="268">AAA</option>
    <option value="409">BBB</option>
    <option value="570">CCC</option>
    <option value="895">DDD</option>
     <option value="943">Arena</option>
    </select>

<select id="origen_2" class="origen">
<option value="268">AAA</option>
<option value="409">BBB</option>
<option value="570">CCC</option>
<option value="895">DDD</option>
<option value="943">Arena</option>
    </select>
</form>
```

And my Javascript is this:

```
   $("body").on('change',"#destino_1", function(){ 
      $("#origen_2").trigger("cambiaOrigen");
   });


$('body').on('cambiaOrigen', '.origen', function() {
    var nombre=this.id;
    var numero=parseInt(nombre.slice(-1));
    //alert("Mooooo " + nombre);
    if (numero > 1) {
        var anterior = $("#destino_" + (numero - 1)).val();
        this.find("option[value='" + anterior + "']").prop("selected", "selected").change();
        //this.val(anterior);
        }
    });
```

I've created a fiddle at http://jsfiddle.net/w7c4o4cd/

As you can see, the event gets correctly triggered, the code gets the value of the first dropdown... but then I can't change the value of the second dropdown. I've tried both ways: with

```
this.find("option[value='" + anterior + "']").prop("selected", "selected").change();
```

And also with `this.val(anterior);`. Neither of them work. When executing in a browser, the error I get in the console is that `this.find` and `this.val()` are not functions... and yet, if you try to display `this.id`, it seems that `this` is referring correctly to the second dropdown, instead of to, say, `body`. (Also, if I try to display `this`, it says that it's an "HTML selectElement").

What's going on?

Comment: Is there any problem with Dhiraj's solution? Looks both accurate and elegant to me. `Musa` has some good information about `this` and `$(this)`, though. +1 to both of them. And I dont' know if anyone mentioned yet - the reason for needing `.on()` is usually because the elements were not present when the DOM was first rendered. See http://davidwalsh.name/event-delegate

Comment: Yeah, that's exactly my problem (I didn't want to mention it to avoid overcomplicating things): the 2nd dropdown gets added to the DOM later. Does Dhiraj's solution work in that case too?

Comment: Dhiraj's answer is using `.on()` so it would catch events triggered on elements later added to the DOM. Note that .on is about catching user events. The programmatic manipulation of injected DOM elements ***just works*** -- that is, if the element exists in the DOM at the instant the code tries to access it, there won't be any problem. *There is no particular method required to manipulate injected DOM elements.*

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just change this line

```
this.find("option[value='" + anterior + "']").prop("selected", "selected").change();
```

to this

```
$(this).find("option[value='" + anterior + "']").prop("selected", "selected").change();
```

Answer (score 3):

In your `cambiaOrigen` handler, `this` refers to a node not a jQuery object, what you would want is `$(this)` instead.
Also to set the selected option of a `select` tag you can simply set its value

```
this.value = anterior;
```

http://jsfiddle.net/mowglisanu/w7c4o4cd/2/

```js
   $("body").on('change',"#destino_1", function(){ $("#origen_2").trigger("cambiaOrigen");
       
   });


$('body').on('cambiaOrigen', '.origen', function() {
 var nombre=this.id;
 var numero=parseInt(nombre.slice(-1));
 //alert("Mooooo " + nombre);
 if (numero > 1) {
  var anterior = $("#destino_" + (numero - 1)).val();
  //alert("Meeeept " + anterior);
        //alert (this);
  this.value = anterior;
  //this.val(anterior);
  }
 });
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<form>
    
    <select id="destino_1">
    <option value="268">AAA</option><option value="409">BBB</option><option value="570">CCC</option><option value="895">DDD</option><option value="943">Arena</option>
    </select>

<select id="origen_2" class="origen">
<option value="268">AAA</option><option value="409">BBB</option><option value="570">CCC</option><option value="895">DDD</option><option value="943">Arena</option>
    </select>
</form>
```

Answer (score 1):

Just set the value of the section dropdown based on the value of the first like this.

```
$("body").on('change', "#destino_1", function () {
   $('#origen_2').val($(this).val());
});
```

```js
   $("body").on('change', "#destino_1", function () {
       $('#origen_2').val($(this).val());
   });
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<form>
    <select id="destino_1">
        <option value="268">AAA</option>
        <option value="409">BBB</option>
        <option value="570">CCC</option>
        <option value="895">DDD</option>
        <option value="943">Arena</option>
    </select>
    <select id="origen_2" class="origen">
        <option value="268">AAA</option>
        <option value="409">BBB</option>
        <option value="570">CCC</option>
        <option value="895">DDD</option>
        <option value="943">Arena</option>
    </select>
</form>
```